# Where to get the frog miniatures?

Tags: guild-wars

I am collecting miniatures in the game and I am trying to get them all. I heard that there was three frog miniatures, but I can't find them anywhere in the game. Some people told me it was some unique items. Is that really the case? Is there no way to get any of those miniatures in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed no way to get those frog miniatures in game. They have been given to a old Arena Net member called Gaile Gray, to thank her for her work. She is the only one to have those miniatures.